# How does a list of function work in Python?

Tags: python, list

I saw a code (these functions are from sklearn module imports)

```
classifiers = [
    LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
    GaussianNB(),
    KNeighborsClassifier(3),
    SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.25),
    SVC(gamma=2, C=1),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2),
    AdaBoostClassifier(),
    ]
```

I was trying to understand what the above code does, so I tried playing with a small test

But, when I do this,

```
def function0():
    print("0")

def function1():
    print("1")

lst = [function0(), function1()]

for i in range(2):
    print(lst[i])
```

it prints,

```
0
1
None
None
```

I believe I understood the code wrong... Could anyone help me understand what I'm missing?

--------------------------------- edit -------------------------------

```
def function0():
    return 0

def function1():
    return 1

lst = [function0(), function1()]

for i in range(2):
    print(lst[i])
```

I figured out what I did wrong.

Comment: You are calling the functions when you're putting them in the list. Don't use parentheses when declaring the list, and use parentheses when iterating through the list elements. Also, you don't need the `print` inside the loop, as the functions don't return anything

Comment: `function0()` and `function1()` are both `None` (so your `lst` contains 2 `None` values) - but in computing that, the functions are called, which is what prints the `0` and `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I see what I missed!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have modified the code so it will be easy to understand.
The 2 functions are called and print what they print.
Each function return `None` so the list is populated with 2 None values

```
def function0():
    print("0")
    return None


def function1():
    print("1")
    return None


lst = [function0(), function1()]
print('-------------------')
for i in range(2):
    print(lst[i])
```

output

```
0
1
-------------------
None
None
```

Comment: While this code may help the OP come to the answer themselves, it'd be better to also add the right code and add a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies what I did wrong in my testing

Comment: I can see no reason for a down vote. I think the answer explain the issue very well. (As you can read above - the OP think the same)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you functions return nothing (which is assumed to be `None` when called).

You can try this instead:

```
def function0():
    print("0")

def function1():
    print("1")

lst = [function0, function1]

for func in lst:
    func()
```